# Is @PreDestroy called after an exception in @PostConstruct in JavaEE 6?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, java-ee-6, cdi

Currently, we have an issue with a more complex initialization in a @PostConstruct method on JavaEE 6. There are several places where something could go wrong and where an exception is to be expected. In that case we might have a half initialized bean.

Is in such a case the @PreDestroy method called? We could check our resources there and free them if necessary. Or do we need to catch all exceptions in @PostConstruct and cleanup everything there? The specification is not clear on that (or maybe I did not find it).

Or, is it vendor specific due to a lack of specification? How is it on JBoss 7.x?

Answer (score 3):

I think the EJB3.1 specification is clear in this case: if you acquired unmanaged resources in PostConstruct then you have to release them yourself in case of an exception.

Section 14.3.3 - Exceptions from PostConstruct and PreDestroy Methods of a Session Bean
Container Action: Log the exception or error.
                  If Singleton, rollback any container-started transaction.
                  Discard instance.

Section 14.3.11 - Release of Resources
When the container discards an instance because of a system exception, the container should release all the resources held by the instance that were acquired through the resource factories declared in the enterprise bean environment (See Subsection 16.7).

Note: While the container should release the connections to the resource managers that the instance acquired through the resource factories declared in the enterprise bean environment, the container cannot, in general, release “unmanaged” resources that the instance may have acquired through the JDK APIs. For example, if the instance has opened a TCP/IP connection, most container implementations will not be able to release the connection. The connection will be eventually released by the JVM garbage collector mechanism.

The following 2 sections specify that @PreDestroy methods are not invoked when a RuntimeException occurs inside and EJB business method or in @PostContruct:

4.7.3Dealing with Exceptions
A RuntimeException that is not an application exception thrown from any method of the enterprise bean class (including the business methods and the lifecycle callback interceptor methods invoked by the container) results in the transition to the “does not exist” state. Exception handling is described in detail in Chapter 14. See section 12.5.1 for the rules pertaining to lifecycle callback interceptor methods when more than one such method applies to the bean class.
From the client perspective, the session object continues to exist. The client can continue accessing the session object because the container can delegate the client’s requests to another instance.

12.5.1Exceptions
Lifecycle callback interceptor methods may throw system runtime exceptions, but not application exceptions.
A runtime exception thrown by any lifecycle interceptor callback method causes the bean instance and its interceptors to be discarded[59] after the interceptor chain unwinds.
The PreDestroy callbacks are not invoked when the bean and the interceptors are discarded as a result of such exceptions: the lifecycle callback interceptor methods in the chain should perform any necessary clean-up operations as the interceptor chain unwinds.

Comment: Yes, that is clear, but it does not answer my question (or maybe I did not understand your answer). Everything I aquire in @PostConstruct, I have to take care of the release. That's for sure and there is no doubt. The question is: Can I do it in @PreDestroy? The spec is not clear. The container goes from 'does not exist' state into 'method-ready pool'. What happens exactly, when the transition cannot be performed? The transitions are explained well, but not the error scenarios.